# Windows 10 setting up windows account management for multiple pcs in small business with a qnap nas server

Tags: windows, windows-10, user-accounts, nas, small-business-server

I have a small business atm and wanna upgrade it to windows 10 next year.

My businesshas: 6 computers(win 7) with 5 users and a NAS server.

Problem: I want every user be able to login on every computer with all his directories and be able to continue his work.

Solution so far: I set up every user on every PC and made all their user directory's directing to the NAS server. but u all may guess what a pain it is to set this up... especially if a user is joining/leaving the team....

Research i done: hours of asking google the wrong questions and checking out Windows server editions......

so i look for a better solution or any advice pls help me :)

thx in advance!

Comment: Why can't you just do in-place upgrades of your existing systems?

Answer (score 0):

What you have done and are using is commonly called *workgroup mode*, where each client needs to authenticate with username and password (which is usually done by adding each user account to each server/NAS).

The alternative would be *domain mode*, which requires and Active Directory domain controller. This can be any Windows server running Windows Server 2000, 2003, 2008, 2008R2, 2012, 2012R2 or 2016 (licensing costs apply); or a Unix/Linux server running Samba 4.0 and newer (licenses usually free).